# Commutative rings among whose proper subrings (with unity) , there exist a unique field

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity , let us say $R$ has property P if the following holds : There exists a unique field among all proper subrings of $R$ (with the same unity as that of $R$) .

My question is :  Let $R$ be a ring with property P which is not a field ; then does $R[X]$ also has property P ?

Note that it is necessary to assume $R$ is not a field . Otherwise say $R=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ has property P but clearly $R[X]$ doesn't .

If $R$ has non non -zero nilpotent then $R[X]^{\times}=R^{\times}$ and $R$ has property P and if $F$ is the unique proper subfield of $R$ , then $F$ is also a subfield of $R[X]$ . If $K$ is any other subfield of $R[X]$ , then $K \setminus \{0\} \subseteq R[X]^{\times}=R^{\times}$ implies $K \subseteq R$ and $R$ is not a field and $R$ has property P then implies $K=F$ .  So if $Nil(R)=\{0\}$ and $R$ is not a field and has property P, then so does $R[X]$ .

This is what I have observed about rings with property P : $R$ properly contains $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Z_p$ ( for some prime $p$ ) as a subring according as $char R=0$ or positive ; let us call this unique subfield of $R$ the prime subfield . If $R$ is an integral domain , and we consider $R$ as a subring of its field of fractions, then  either every element of $R\setminus F $ ( this is non-empty) is transcendental over $F$ or some  $a \in R\setminus F$ is algebraic over $F$ , in which case $R=F[a]$ is a field and so $[R:F] < \infty$ ; where $F$ is the prime subfield of $R$. If $R$ it self is a field with prime subfield $F$ , and $t \in R \setminus F$ is transcendental , then $F \subseteq F(t^2) \subseteq F(t) \subseteq R$ and $F \ne F(t^2) , F(t) \ne F(t^2)$ shows then $R$ has more than one proper subfield ; hence no element in $R$ can be transcendental over $F$ if $R$ is a field , and $R=F[b]=F(b) , \forall b \in R \setminus F$ . So moreover , if $R$ is a field of positive characteristic , then $R$ is a finite extension over $\mathbb Z_p$ , so let $R \cong F_{p^n}$ , but then property P implies $n=[R : \mathbb Z_p]$ has to be a prime  . Hence a field $R$  of positive characteristic has property P if an only if $R \cong F_{p^q}$ for some primes $p$ and $q$ , where $p=char R$ .

Answer (score 1):

I think a ring $R$ has property $P$ if and only if $R^{\times}$ is (isomorphic to) either $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ or $\mathbb{Q}^*$.

Indeed if $R$ has property $P$, denote $k$ its unique subfield. Because $k$ cannot contain any subfield, it's either $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ (depending on its characteristic). Then I claim that $k^* = R^{\times}$ : we know that $k^* \subset R^{\times}$, and if $x \in R$ is an invertible element outside of $k$, then $k(x)$ is another subfield of $R$ (which is impossible, so no such $x$ exist). So we have one way.

To prove the other implication, we assume that $R^{\times}$ is either $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ or $\mathbb{Q}^*$. Now if $k$ is a subfield of $R$, then $k^*\subset R^{\times}$ but since the fields $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ have no proper subfield, then $k^*=R^{\times}$ and we're done.

Now using this criterion, I think we can prove that $R[X]$ inherits property $P$ since $R[X]^{\times}=R^{\times}$.

Comment: $k[x]$ is a subfield if and only if $x$ is algebraic over $k$ ... how do you know it is algebraic ?

Comment: and also ... any field of order $p^q$ , for primes $p,q$ have property P  .. so I don't see how you get it ... are you assuming $R$ is not a field ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $k(x)$ there's no assumption on whether or not $x$ is algebraic.

Comment: Now that you raise the problem I understand the issue with the proof : if $x$ is algebraic with a composite minimal polynomial, then $k[x]$ is not even an integral domain.

Comment: what do you mean by " composite minimal polynomial " ? I think your proof of $k^{\times}=R^{\times}$ is correct assuming $R$ is not a field ... $x \in R^{\times}$ implies have $k(x)$ is a subfield of $R$ , so there are two possibilities : $R=k(x)$ or $k(x)=k$ , which along with $R$ is not a field implies $k(x)=k$ i.e. $x \in k^{\times}$ . So $R^{\times} \subseteq k^{\times} $ . Very nice argument . I am yet to see the converse .

Comment: the comment I made above is correct only if $R$ an integral domain ... and for non-field integral domains your characterization is correct .... but for non-field integral domains I already know the property passes to polynomial rings

Answer (score 0):

Edit: OP points out that this argument only works if $R$ has no non-zero nilpotents.

Yes, because if $F\subset R[X]$ is a field with the same unity as $R[X]$ (and thus the same one as $R$), then in fact $F\subset R$ because the only invertible elements in $R[X]$ are in $R^*$ (the units of $R$) and every non-zero element in $F$ needs to be invertible. So $F$ is unique, since $R$ has property $P$.

More generally if you want your ring $R$ to have the property $P$, you want the largest field they contain to be either $\mathbb Q$ or a unique $\mathbb F_p$ a finite field.

Comment: $R[X]^{\times}=R^{\times}$ is true if and only if $R$ has non non-zero nilpotent

Comment: see my edit . I have made further conclusions

Comment: @users I see. I am thinking that in the general case suppose there is a unique $F\subsetneq R$ and suppose there is a bigger $F'\subset R[X]$. Then we have a field extension $F\subsetneq F'$ and if this is an algebraic extension, then for any $f\in F'\backslash F \subsetneq R[X]\backslash R$, we'd be able to show that $X$ is algebraic, a contradiction. So we are left with the case that $F\subset F'$ is transcendental so somehow $R[X]$ contains a rational function field $F(t)$ for some $t$ a unit in $R[X]^*$. I don't see further but see if you can use this to conclude (or get a counterexample).